# Issues with xlwings and win32api

Tags: python, excel, winapi, xlwings

This is my first time trying to work with xlwings and the documentation on their site says that win32api is required to use xlwings. 
http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/installation.html

So I followed their link to win32api and downloaded the latest version, which to get the latest version I needed to go to their gethub.
https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases

When connecting to Python in CMD I get: Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

So I downloaded pywin32-223.win32-py3.6.exe and ran the installer. It finished successfully and when I try and run

```
import xlwings as xw

def viewEquipment():
    wb = xw.Book(r'FilePath\FileName.xlsx')
    test = wb.Range('D3').value
    print(test)
```

I get the error "import win32api
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd recommend using pip: `pip install xlwings` Let pip handle the dependencies for you. (You may need to run `python -m pip install -U pip` to upgrade PIP before it finds the appropriate package)

Comment: I did update pip as you recommended and when I run `pip install xlwings' I get C:\Users\Brent_Lageson>pip install xlwings
Requirement already satisfied: xlwings in c:\users\brent_lageson\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (0.11.7)
Requirement already satisfied: comtypes in c:\users\brent_lageson\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from xlwings) (1.1.4)

Comment: pip install pypiwin32

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xlwings No module named 'win32api'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795408/xlwings-no-module-named-win32api)