# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32.api'

Tags: python, pycharm, xlwings

When I tried to import xlwings using `import xlwings as xw`, it shows the following error:

```
from win32.api import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32.api'
```

My environment is:

1. Windows 10
2. Python 3.10
3. IDE: PyCharm

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Have you write this line of code `from win32.api import *` to execute? If you have a python file to execute please provide all the necessary code details for others to help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xlwings No module named 'win32api'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795408/xlwings-no-module-named-win32api)

Comment: Code:
import xlwings as xw

Result:
Traceback (most recent call last):

    import xlwings as xw
    from .udfs import (
    import pythoncom
    from win32com import *
    import win32api, sys, os
    from win32.api import *
\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\win32api\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32.api'

Comment: Please do NOT provide details (especially not code and/or error messages) in comments. Instead, [edit] your question and extend it with the requested information. Also, please make sure to keep the formatting of your stacktrace correct (use three backticks before and after the stacktrace that you copy-pasted).

Answer (score -1):

You probably don't have the `pywin32` module installed.

Try `pip install pywin32` and check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795408/xlwings-no-module-named-win32api)

Comment: Yes, I do have "pywin32" version 304, and it's weird that the error is "win32.api", not 'win32api". BTW, my pycharm version is 2022.1.1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this answer might be useful for the OP, if it has already been answered here, it's better to flag a question as duplicate instead of repeating the answer.